# What is the biblical basis that we no longer need to confess and repent?

Tags: biblical-basis, sin, confession, repentance, free-grace-theology

[Joseph Prince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Prince) (Worldwide speaker and author of *Destined to Reign*) and [Andrew Wommack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Wommack) (Andrew Wommack Ministries and author of many books) teaches this with the Grace (hyperGrace) message, as does my local Pastor. They say we are already forgiven for our past, present, and future sins, and because of that our sins are overlooked. So there's no need to confess our sins, ask forgiveness, and repent.

What is the Biblical basis for this belief?

Comment: IMO, there isn't other than to explain away the verses in 1 John, which they did, by attributing it to refer to Jewish believers.

Comment: Joseph uses many scriptures for justifying his beliefs. Look at the many verses taken out of context here: http://www.josephprince.org/daily-grace/grace-inspirations/?topic=Forgiveness%20of%20Sins

Comment: I don't think either of those guys are actually Free Grace teachers, can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 4):

Like most good lies, there is a kernel of truth here hiding underneath the perversion of the Gospel.

Scripture is quite clear that Christ died for *repentant* sinners. Because God exists outside of time, and because Christ's Death is temporally in the past, it is correct to say that all sins of those who are saved, including future sins, are already forgiven. However, confession and repentance are absolutely still necessary.

Paul is pretty clear about this (Romans 6):

> Are we to continue in sin that grace may abound? By no means! [...] Are we to sin because we are not under law but under grace? By no means!

**Maybe** you could ask whether forgiveness precedes repentance, but Scripture is quite clear that one who simply continues to live Sin is not saved. Someone who *is* saved will naturally turn from Sin toward Christ, which would naturally lead to confession and repentance *even if it isn't necessary*. These are fruits of faith, and faith without fruits is dead (James 2). Anyone who believes "there's no need to confess our sins, ask forgiveness, and repent" deceives themselves. Anyone who teaches this to others, deceives others, and woe to that person on the day of judgment (Matthew 18:6).

Answer (score 4):

Before attempting to find out what the biblical basis is for believing Christians no longer need to confess and repent (according to Joseph Prince and Andrew Wommack), we first **need to establish what Hyper Grace is.**  This article defines [hyper grace](https://www.gotquestions.org/hyper-grace.html) as:

> a new wave of teaching that emphasizes the grace of God to the exclusion of other vital teachings such as repentance and confession of sin. Hyper-grace teachers maintain that all sin, past, present, and future, has already been forgiven, so there is no need for a believer to ever confess it. Hyper-grace teaching says that, when God looks at us, He sees only a holy and righteous people. The conclusion of hyper-grace teaching is that we are not bound by Jesus’ teaching, even as we are not under the Law; that believers are not responsible for their sin; and that anyone who disagrees is a pharisaical legalist. In short, hyper-grace teachers “pervert the grace of our God into a license for immorality” (Jude 1:4) and flirt with antinomianism.

Is this what Joseph Prince teaches?  This [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Prince) does not answer that specific question, but it does list some of the books published by Joseph Prince:

> Destined to Reign – the secret to effortless success, wholeness and victorious living -2007

> Health and Wholeness through holy communion- 2009

> Unmerited Favor – your supernatural advantage for a successful life – 2011

> Give me this Mountain – faith to go from barely surviving to actually thriving – 2020

Joseph Prince is the senior pastor of [New Creation Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Creation_Church) but theology is not discussed:

> New Creation Church is a non-denominational Charismatic Christian megachurch in Singapore. Founded in 1984, it holds services at The Star Performing Arts Centre. It is a member of the National Council of Churches of Singapore (NCCS).  The church was one of three megachurches to make it to a list of Singapore's 10 largest charities, according to a report by The Straits Times in 2019. The senior pastor of the church is Joseph Prince.

[Andrew Wommack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Wommack) is co-founder of the Truth and Liberty Coalition but does not say if he teaches the doctrine of Hyper Grace:

> Andrew Wommack is an American conservative charismatic TV evangelist and faith healer. He founded Andrew Wommack Ministries in 1978 and Charis Bible College (originally Colorado Bible College) in 1994.  The Gospel Truth television program began on the INSP Network in January 2000 and was eventually carried by other Christian television networks and some individual stations.  Wommack is one of the six co-founders of the Truth and Liberty Coalition, a dominionist organization that believes God has given Christians "a mandate to bring Godly change to our world, through the seven spheres of societal influence," i.e., religion and faith; family; education; government and law; media, news and commentary; arts and entertainment; and business and economics.

**What then is the biblical basis for believing Christians no longer need to confess and repent?**

**We are saved by grace, not by works (Ephesians 2:8–9):**

> 8 For by grace you have been saved through faith. And this is not your own doing; it is the gift of God, 9 not a result of works, so that no one may boast.

**God’s grace is a wonderful and free gift (1 Timothy 1:14):**

> 14 and the grace of our Lord overflowed for me with the faith and love that are in Christ Jesus.

**The only confession that is required is to confess Jesus as Lord (Romans 10:9):**

> 9 because, if you confess with your mouth that Jesus is Lord and believe in your heart that God raised him from the dead, you will be saved.

They emphasise the beauty and power of God’s grace and the forgiveness of God – which is good – but then claim the Holy Spirit will never convict Christians of their sin.  Hyper-grace preachers also deny that the Apostle John’s letters were written to believers, therefore the admonition in 1 John 1:9 and 1 John 2:1 does not apply to Christians.

**Conclusion:** The difficulty in finding a biblical basis for Hyper Grace is that it is based on the belief that the Old Testament and the Ten Commandments are irrelevant to New Testament believers, and that Jesus’ words spoken before His resurrection are part of the Old Covenant and no longer applicable to born-again believers.  However, the question asks what the biblical basis for this teaching is, and I’m afraid the Bible verses quoted above are all I could find.

Comment: Scripture also rejects the idea of "hyper grace"; n.b. James 2:14-26 and Matthew 7:21 (and my Answer). While James 2 is sometimes used to pervert Sola Gratia, that is not its correct use. While it is true that we are not saved *by* works, someone who does not confess and repent almost certainly does not have saving faith in the first place.

Comment: Then again, considering how many people misuse James 2, I suppose it shouldn't be surprising that some people make the opposite mistake. Confession and repentance aren't legalistic works which save us by their own power, but they *are* works — that is, fruits — as James 2 discusses them, without which one is almost certainly not saved. Saying that they "aren't necessary" may contain an element of truth, but trying to brush them aside is not consistent with a living faith.

Comment: @Matthew - I up-voted your answer and agree with you that confession and repentance  come from the fruit of the Spirit. It also concerns me that some of those "mega churches" are so focused on health, wealth and prosperity.

Comment: Absolutely! While there are notable examples of Godly men who were also very wealthy, the *pursuit* of earthly wealth is idolatry, and one ought to keep Matthew 19:24 in mind. And Matthew 5:1-12, for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

> OP:  They say we are already forgiven for our past, present, and future sins, and because of that our sins are overlooked. So there's no need to confess our sins, ask forgiveness, and repent.
> What is the Biblical basis for this belief?

Couple of background points.

It is true our sins past, present, and future are forgiven in Christ.

> But to him that worketh not, but believeth on him that justifieth the ungodly, his faith is counted for righteousness. Even as David also describeth the blessedness of the man, unto whom God imputeth righteousness without works, Saying, Blessed are they whose iniquities are forgiven, and whose sins are covered. Blessed is the man to whom the Lord will not impute sin. Romans 4:5-8

> Wherefore he is able also to save them to the uttermost that come unto God by him, seeing he ever liveth to make intercession for them. Heb 7:25

John's baptism was of repentance.

> John did baptize in the wilderness, and preach the baptism of repentance for the remission of sins. Mark 1:4

Repentance [means](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g3341/kjv/tr/0-1/) "change of mind".  What were they changing their mind about?  The Mosaic Law's message that IF you do all of this LAW, THEN you will be forgiven (Deut 6:25).  Recall that John was to make straight the path of the Lord (Isa 40:3).

Is the baptism of repentance for the Christian?

> And he said unto them, Unto what then were ye baptized? And they said, Unto John's baptism. Then said Paul, John verily baptized with the baptism of repentance, saying unto the people, that they should believe on him which should come after him, that is, on Christ Jesus. When they heard this, they were baptized in the name of the Lord Jesus. Acts 19:3-5

Change your mind, repent, of whatever else you think might "save" you, and be baptized in the name of Jesus Christ (or Trinity).

Now, to the question.

Once you are a believer, what about your sins?

We ask forgiveness, not because God is ready to send a thunderbolt your way, but because of your human relationship within the Body of Christ first, but also of those outside who we might offend.

> Wherefore, if meat make my brother to offend, I will eat no flesh while the world standeth, lest I make my brother to offend. 1 Cor 8:13

So, to answer the OP, our sins are forgiven and forgotten (Psalm 103:12, Heb 10:10).

Still, we need to confess our sins and ask forgiveness and repent for the Body of CHrist.

PS. To be saved by grace through faith in Christ Jesus in the first place, we must acknowledge we are sinners (Rom 5:8, 1 Tim 1:5).

Answer (score 0):

"Confess" is mentioned 16 times in the Old Testament, while the word "Repent" is mentioned 24 times. In the New Testament it is 10 vs 54. Thus, the word "repent" is mentioned about two times more than the word "confess" in the Old Testament, while in the New Testament it shoots up to about five times more. Consequently, repenting is more important than confessing in the Old Testament, but even more so in the New Testament.

It would be logical to think that to repent from a life in sin we first must confess that there is a problem. Question is; except to God whom should we confess to? To people? If so, to how many people, and to whom exact? I am venturing that it will vary according to circumstances. Thus, if someone invites us to join them on a night out, with wine, women, and song, or to smuggle drugs, etc. then we, to be able to continue living a repentant life, should confess that we don't do that stuff any more.

It wouldn't be to much use to confess our sins to people if we have no intention to change our way of life.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about what the question is asking about.

Answer (score -1):

This text declares exactly what one must believe to receive salvation.

I Corinthians 15:1-4

> <sup>1</sup>Moreover, brethren, I declare unto you the gospel which I preached unto you, which also ye have received, and wherein ye stand;
> <sup>2</sup>By which also ye are saved, if ye keep in memory what I preached unto you, unless ye have believed in vain.
> <sup>3</sup>For I delivered unto you first of all that which I also received, how that Christ died for our sins according to the scriptures;
> <sup>4</sup>And that he was buried, and that he rose again the third day according to the scriptures:

The "if" is not conditional and could be translated " seeing that..."

Paul also said, "I did not come to baptize but to preach the gospel." (I Corinthians 1:17).

The Gospel of the Circumcision requires repentance and water baptism, but the Gospel of the Uncircumcision ( I e. Romans) requires only belief.

I believe this verse sums it up for Christians today...

Ephesians 1:13b, 14

> <sup>13b</sup>in whom also after that ye believed, ye were sealed with that holy Spirit of promise,
> <sup>14</sup>Which is the earnest of our inheritance until the redemption of the purchased possession, unto the praise of his glory.

The exact moment one believes, he or she is sealed with The Holy Spirit. Nothing can add to that or take away from it, especially works of the flesh.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question of biblical basis for the teaching that confession of and repentance for sin is no longer necessary.

Comment: If one is saved the moment they believe, nothing further is necessary. If anything else was necessary, salvation would be conditional upon doing those things but it is by "solo fide" faith alone. All else is "window dressing" and goes back to the "old age" of symbols and types and "shadows of things to come." Those things have been fulfilled for us in Christ. Our entire salvation is wrapped up in him alone and God even gives us the faith to believe (Romans 10:17).

Comment: If one does not think they have need to confess then that one is in a dangerous place.  "If we say we have no sin, we deceive ourselves, and the truth is not in us. If we confess our sins, he is faithful and just to forgive us our sins and to cleanse us from all unrighteousness. If we say we have not sinned, we make him a liar, and his word is not in us. - 1 John 1:8-10"  This is written to born again believers.

Comment: I appreciate your response and would have agreed with you a few years ago before I learned the difference between the joint-body of Christ which is now being formed and the Circumcision church which has been held in abeyance until our present church is taken up to meet our Lord in the air. Paul never implores us to confess our sins in his epistles - he only tells Israel to in Romans 19:9,10 ( note the context). John was a Circumcision apostle as were the rest of the 12. Paul is the apostle to the Gentiles.

Comment: Confessing to God isn't a formula for restoration, it's part of sanctification.  It is inevitable that I will fall short and the discipline of my heavenly Father (if I do not despise it) will lead me to realize my error.  If at that point I merely say "No big deal, that sin is forgiven" rather than confess and repent (change my mind) I should begin to suspect my motives.  In my understanding, confession does not determine or restore relationship, it is part of it.

Comment: Mike, we have been justified which goes beyond forgiveness of sins. Justification is an irreversible legal acquittal of all charges.  We have been sealed with the Holy Spirit until the day of redemption, and cannot be unsealed.  We have been made the righteousness of God in Christ and nothing, not even our own sin can reverse that. When we sin, we acknowledge it and renew our minds to do what is right and make any restitution necessary and move on.

Comment: Agreed.  I just call this part, "When we sin, we acknowledge it and renew our minds to do what is right and make any restitution necessary and move on", confession and repentance.  The idea that confession to my Father of sin against my Father (which is all of them) is no longer appropriate does not sit well with me.  When he shows me through Spirit or Word that I am thinking, acting, or speaking wrong...I confess it:  I say the same thing about the sin that He says, and that carries a tone of apology.  If I do not confess (admit to Him that He is right and I am wrong) I cannot renew my mind.

Comment: I agree in principle because when offending a human I still feel the need to apologize and make it right as I can. Because of justification, I don't believe God "breaks fellowship" with us, but at the Bena, any wrongs I have committed that I have not made restitution for (I mean by my actions to make things right, recompense) will be made right then. All things will be settled between believers at the Bema. Now is the best alternative. God bless you.

Comment: Do you think that those who will be saved as if through fire (1 Cor 3:15) or those who become sick or sleep (1 Cor. 11:30) are thus because of relations between believers?

Comment: Interesting thought Mike, I have to investigate further.